# iPad Calorie Counter App

Tags: calories, daily-caloric-intake, app

The Calorie Counter app I downloaded onto my iPad measures intake as Calories and energy burned as `kcal`. So, if the calorie counter says that the total calories burned is `2451 kcal` is it the same as `2451` Calories burned?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of nutrition (food Calories), `1 Calorie = 1 Kcal = 1000 calories`. So *assuming* your iPad app is correct in reporting `2451 kcal`, then **yes**, you burned `2451` Calories.